# Android Bluetooth inputstream behaviour

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, inputstream

Hi: The following functions are expected to be called consecutively in an android phone app, which is connected to an Arduino Chip through HC-06 bluetooth module. 
The connection works. 
I'm expecting that after I use "sendInitialCommand()", the Arduino would send back unknown length of bytes (let's say maybe 20 bytes), a byte at a time using loops.
I wonder if my "handleInitialComeback()" would work properly?
Is the mmInputStream.available() going to return 20 (or whatever the actual length Arduino send)? Would the the bytes be separated by unknown number of 0s? Or would the read() function give me the exact bytes the Arduino sent?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-TJbGBURiUOM0ZPcXIxYUczYzQ&authuser=0

Comment: The code is on google drive

Comment: I don't have the reputation to post picture yet